# (vb.net) Why GeckoFX 31 buildID cannot be detected by sites?

Tags: vb.net, xul, xulrunner, geckofx

I'm building a web browser in vb.net using geckofx 31 and xulrunner 31. I need web sites to think I am navigating with a regular Firefox 31.
If I run http://browserspy.dk/showprop.php with a regular Firefox 31 it detects the buildID (should be 20140716183446), but when I run it on my GeckoFX31/XULRunner31 browser, buildID is null (blank).
Do you have any suggestions how to make my GeckoFX31/XULRunner31 browser seem more like a regular Firefox 31?
I do all this because I need to enhance functionality. 
Thanks!

Comment: If you want to build a web browser with enhanced functionality, it seams that it might be easier to start with the full Firefox source code and build from scratch, with modifications, rather than try to build upon XULRunner/GeckoFX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the buildID via the general.buildID.override setting.

```
GeckoPreferences.Default("general.buildID.override") = "20140716183446"
```